# Deleting documents using firebase admin, doesn't reflect on the edge devices

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

We have a Firebase Realtime Database running on mobile apps.
We want to clean the DB once in while to keep is small(ish).
I tried to delete documents using Firebase admin. what I see is:

- The data doesn't appear in the realtime console.
- The data still exist in the edge devices that already read this data in the past

Is there a way to "flush" the edge device memory? To clean it?
Some other ID?
Thanks

I already tried restart the app and added a timestamp filtering

Comment: Answer below. If that doesn't fully answer your question, please answer the question to include the code that you use to read the data on the devices, and the code that deletes the data.

Answer (score 0):

The cache on the device will delete the data once you perform another read for that data from the server. It won't be deleted before that, as the SDK has no way to know on its own that the data was deleted until it checks with the server (which it only does when your code tells it to read the data from the server).

There is no way to clear the device's cache through the API.

Comment: Frank- So if data is not deleted, and my app keeps fetching data from the cloud (i.e. syncing), at some point it will crash. As the memory keeps growing all the time.

The only way out that I have is to delete data from my DB and make the app re-read the data?
It seems like a bad practice

Comment: Did you see the comment I left under your question? If my posted answer doesn't fully address your question, please post a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and if possible the debug output about what data is read, how much memory is used, and other variables you seem concerned about) as it's hard to reason on your app's behavior without those.